# Unable to follow sandbox link in Apache Mesos

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, mesos

I have a mesos cluster setup with a master and slave on separate hosts on GCE. In the mesos console I can see the list of tasks - but the sandbox link isn't working.

I'm getting this error

```
Failed to connect to slave '20150806-140802-3049385994-5050-1-S0' on '4c37a1dd950b:5051'.
Potential reasons:
The slave's hostname, '4c37a1dd950b', is not accessible from your network
The slave's port, '5051', is not accessible from your network
The slave timed out or went offline
```

4c37a1dd950b is on the same server as the master.

Any tips appreciated

Comment: In the end I stopped trying to run everything in a container i.e. Mesos on bare metal, everything else in containers...workaround but its fine for me.